# How to use division of jsp page from a java class?

Tags: java, api, jsp, email, html

I am using Java mail api to send emails but, i want to pass division of a jsp page to content of mail.

**JAVA CODE**

```
             Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abc@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse("xyz@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Subject");
        message.setText("div=todayactionitems");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");
```

**JSP PAGE DIVISION**

```
  <table id="todayactionitems" class="actionItems">
  <thead id="todayhead">
  <tr>
    <th width="1" class="leftside">&nbsp;</th>
    <th width="23"><div class="collapse" style="width:20px;">&#8211;</div></th>
    <th width="308"><div style="width:260px;">Today</div></th>
```

So, that email sent must contain content of dividion (todayactionitems)

Answer (score 1):

you can use html tags directly in the text what you are sending

like

```
 String someHtmlMessage = "<div>.............</div>";

 message.setContent(someHtmlMessage, "text/html; charset=utf-8")
```

Note that the HTML should not contain the ,  or . Gmail will ignore it.

Comment: I am not talking about html tag div. I want content of div present in one of my jsp page to be used here.

Comment: Its a dynamic content which comes from server, every time its changes.